# Python tool to generate a unique temporary filename

Tags: python, temp

To get a unique name for a temporary file you can use [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile). But I want a fifo instead of a regular file, so something like:

```
name = generate_unique_name()  # how?
try:
    os.mkfifo(name)
    # do stuff with the FIFO
finally:
    os.remove(name)
```

Is there a stdlib way to autogenerate a temporary filename which is guaranteed to be unique in a directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python has the [`tempfile` module](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html), which may have what you're looking for in it.

Comment: I did notice the `tempfile` module previously, and I have just read the docs, but it seems to give a handle to a file-like object already open for writing - it is not clear to me how to use it to create a fifo which I can then use for managing some subprocess communication.  How about a usage example in your answer?

Comment: @wim: You could use [`tempfile.mkdtemp`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) to create a directory and put a FIFO in it.

Comment: is there a way to create the fifo directly, possibly using the `mode` argument to `NamedTemporaryFile`?

Comment: @wim: I don't know for sure, but I doubt it.